# проперти объекта

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на такую задачку

```
var bar = function barred() {
  this.a = 4;
};
bar.b = 44;
bar.call(bar);

bar.b;
bar.hasOwnProperty(b); // Ошибка
bar.a;
bar.hasOwnProperty(a); // Ошибка
```

Почему так получается?

Answer (score 5):

Потому что вы кавычки забыли, получается использовали переменные вместо строк.

Правильный вариант

```
bar.hasOwnProperty('b'); 
bar.hasOwnProperty('a');
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы не объявили переменные a и b.